# XSLT, how to find preceding sibling's (text contained) last most child element with text?

Tags: xslt

In the following XML and XSLT, in xml where element 'i' is present location, by there I need to find the preceding-siblings last child text.

Input1.xml

```
  <root>
    <aa>
    <a>
        <b>Text1</b>
        <c>Text2</c>
        <d>Text3
            <n>Text11
                <o>Text12
                    <p>Text13</p>
                </o>
            </n>
        </d>
    </a>
    <e>
        <f>
            <g>Text4</g>
        </f>
        <h>Text5
            <j>Text7</j>
            <k>Text8</k>
        </h>
    </e>
    <i>Text6</i>
    </aa>
  </root>
```

Child.xsl

```
  <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="i">
        <xsl:variable name="var0"><xsl:apply-templates select="preceding-sibling::*[1]"/></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="var1">
            <xsl:for-each select="var0">
                <xsl:value-of select="child::*[last()]"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:variable name="var2">
            <xsl:for-each select="$var1">
                <xsl:value-of select="child::*[last()]"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>

            <ppp><xsl:copy-of select="."/><jj>-The last preceding child text is <xsl:value-of select="$var2"/>-</jj></ppp>
    </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Required output is

> *Text6*The last preceding child text is - Text8

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you mean previous sibling's last descendent non-whitespace, not last child text. (Remember, the indendation you've shown us in the XML file is also text nodes.)

Get the preceding sibling element. Get its text-node descendants. From those select the non-whitespace ones. From those, select the last one.

Should be something like:

```
select="preceding-sibling::*/descendant::text()[normalize-space()!=''][last()]"
```

(where I'm taking advantage of the fact that the principal node type of preceding-sibling is element).

That finds the text node. To get its containing element, add one more step to the path:

```
select="preceding-sibling::*/descendant::text()[normalize-space()!=''][last()]/parent::*"
```

(again, taking advantage of the fact that the principal node type of parent is element).

If you're going to work with XPath and XSLT, it's worth spending some time really getting used to predicates. They're what permits layering complex constraints into a single path, and they add a LOT of power to the language.

Comment: Hi Sir, if element 'i' is child to 'w' like <w><i>Text6</i></w>, then how to find the preceded text of element 'i' s preceded text. Earlier we used 'preceding-sibling', now there is no preceding-sibling, it is having preceded text. Please suggest.

Comment: Sir, for the above text, as you suggested ' preceding::text()[normalize-space()!=''][1]' is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

To test whether a node is of type text you add text() after the selector:

```
preceding-sibling::text()
```

And it seems to me that all you need in var2 is this:

```
preceding::text()
```

and var2 will be the text node you're looking for.

Comment: Preceding::text() won't work. First off, it finds ALL preceding text nodes. Second, if there is a text sibling of the i element; it'll find that text rather than the one that has been requested. And since we see indentation, there *is* such a text sibling.

    preceding::text()[normalize-space()!=''][1]

will find the nearest preceding non-whitespace text sibling, but if there's text between the two elements it still won't find what waws requested.

Comment: I thought of storing preceded element including its child also in variable, by that I can access its last child text area.

Comment: Hi Sir, Sorry for late reply.  preceding::text()[normalize-space()!=''][1], works perfectly. Thanks a lot for your suggestion.